# How to make group of vertices solid/frozen/rigid

Tags: vertex-groups

My apologies, my question may be a duplicate but I can't seem to find the correct terminology to phrase my question correctly.

During editing, is it possible to select a group of vertices and cause them to become 'solid'? As in, make it so that if I translate 1 vertex from the group, the entire group translates together, or if 1 vertex is rotated, the whole group rotates with it as a solid object.

Specifics: I have a model (model and example of what I'm aiming for included below) that I've been making and essentially I want to bend most of it into an arc shape, but I want a section of it to remain rigid so that it doesn't warp while I rotate the rest of it.

[image: Model]

[image: Target]

Comment: Do you mean while editing or during a physics simulation?

Comment: You can use a hook modifier and assign a vertex group to it.

Comment: @maddin45 During editing, sorry. Edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: What does the power ranger have to do with the question?

Comment: I'm modeling the golden vest, it isn't really pertinent but in case the question wasn't clear I included an image of my model and the target of what I'm modeling. I'm trying to bend the vest into an arc shape, but want the diamond to remain flat and rigid.

Comment: For simple things I usually just hide(H) the part I don't want to be affected, do whatever needs to be done and then unhide it(Alt-H).

Comment: did you try proportionnal editing?

Comment: In future it's wise to mention what the image is for. I figured that might be it but it did seem a little random without an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

Separate the objects. In "object mode" hit "shift+d" to duplicate the object. Delete the vertices in one object, and the inverse vertices in the other. Then, while editing one, you do not affect another.

Option 2:

Deform your mesh with an Armature. Use 2 bones. One bone affects the rigid piece, the other bone affects the other parts. Pose the bones into the shape you want, and apply the armature. Use "vertex groups" to influence the deforms. A bone will affect vertices in a vertex group that has the same name as it.

Hopefully this can help you learn some terminology and put you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this up, sounds like the way I was imagining the scenario to work was not how I would actually accomplish it.